# Laravel blank page on request /index.php

Tags: php, laravel

When I go to:

```
http://example.com/index.php?lang=ru //example
```

I get a blank page, but why does laravel not redirect to the main page?

In index.php on directory laravel I changed:

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
  return false;
}
```

to

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
  echo $uri;
  return false;
}
```

And when I go to:

```
http://example.com/index.php?lang=ru
```

I get the message: `/index.php`.

How I can fix this solution?

The logs are empty. App debug is true.

Comment: I guess this is because of your echo statement.

Comment: Nothing in `laravel.log`? Have you set `APP_DEBUG` to true in your `.env`?

Comment: Nope. Errors I not see..

Comment: maybe you are using the wrong version of php.

Comment: @FatemehMajd 7.2.8

Comment: What happens when you go to `http://example.com/index.php`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `index.php` file doesn't have that code. You are changing `server.php`, no? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/d53539b47b6d2a20d0c3d3257ad801bc72547c9d/server.php